# Add lines in PostScript file by command line

Tags: bash, postscript

I have a ps file that is a single A4 page, and I want to draw 4 dotted lines that divided the page in 9 pieces of equals size.

And I need to do that by command line or from a bash script.

Comment: But if you want any more help then you are going to have to be more specific. Exactly where do you want to draw the lines ? What kind of dashes do you want ? What line thickness, what colour ? Do you want the lines drawn before the content on the page, or after ? Is this for a specific page, or for any page ? What have you tried so far ? What results did you get ? In what way were your results unsatisfactory ? Why the requirement to use a command line or bash script ?

Comment: Exactly where do you want to draw the lines? As far I know, there is only a way to divide a page in 9 equals pieces with 4 lines, it is a simple grid with 9 cells. What kind of dashes do you want? No matter, even a straight line would be fine. What line thickness, what colour? 1px would be ok, black or grey would be ok.  Do you want the lines drawn before the content on the page, or after? No matter, there is nothing in the same area. Is this for a specific page, or for any page? As I said, there is a only one page in the ps file so "any page" and "a specific page" is the same. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use a /BeginPage or /EndPage procedure to draw lines, and you can prepend that to the PostScript program.

You could use Ghostscript's ps2write device and add per-page content.

Anyway, simply prepend a PostScript fragment with a call to setpagedevice and have the dictionary contain a BeginPage procedure which draws the four lines you want. Job done

x y moveto x y lineto stroke will draw a line in the current colour, where x and y are the positions in PostScript units (1/72 inch) To set black do "0 setgray" before executing stroke. To figure the page size programmatically either use "currentpagedevice /PageSize get" or "clippath pathbbox". The PostScript Language Reference Manual is available online.

Answer (score 0):

Follow KenS's answers I have done that:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# -eq 0 ]] ; then
    echo 'Tienes que pasar un fichero como argumento'
    exit 0
fi

if [[ ! -f "$1" ]]; then
    echo "$1 no es un fichero"
    exit 0
fi

SOURCE=$(realpath -- "$1")

DIR="$PWD"

cd $(mktemp -d)

echo "Directorio de trabajo: $PWD"

filename=$(basename -- "$1")
extension="${filename##*.}"
filename="${filename%.*}"

WORKCOPY="in.pdf"
OUTPUT="$DIR/${filename}"

if [[ "$extension" != "pdf" ]]; then
    unoconv -f pdf -o "$WORKCOPY" "$SOURCE"
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        exit $?
    fi
else
    cp "$SOURCE" "$WORKCOPY"
    OUTPUT="${OUTPUT}_3x3"
fi

pages=$(pdfinfo "$WORKCOPY" | grep Pages | awk '{print $2}')

if [ $pages -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "El número de páginas ha de ser 2"
    exit 0
fi

function build_page {
    pdftk "$WORKCOPY" cat $1 $1 $1 $1 $1 $1 $1 $1 $1 output "$1.pdf"
    rot=$(pdfinfo "$1.pdf" | grep "Page rot" | awk '{print $3}')
    if [ $rot -ne 0 ]; then
        pdftk "$1.pdf" cat 1-endnorth output "$1_north.pdf"
        mv "$1_north.pdf" "$1.pdf"
    fi

    size=$(pdfinfo "$1.pdf" | grep "Page size" | awk '{print $3, $5}')
    width=$(echo $size | cut -d' ' -f1)
    height=$(echo $size | cut -d' ' -f2)
    pdf2ps "$1.pdf" "$1.ps"
    psnup -W${width} -H${height} -pa4 -9 "$1.ps" "$1_oct.ps"

    if [ $1 -eq 1 ]; then
        # Guias para cortar
        # Ancho: 842
        #  Alto: 595
        cp "$1_oct.ps" "$1_oct.bak.ps"
        cat > "$1_oct.ps" <<EOF
<< /BeginPage
{
    0.7 setgray

    0 280.66 moveto 595 280.66 lineto stroke
    0 561.33 moveto 595 561.33 lineto stroke

    198.33 0 moveto 198.33 842 lineto stroke
    396.66 0 moveto 396.66 842 lineto stroke
}
>> setpagedevice
EOF
        cat "$1_oct.bak.ps" >> "$1_oct.ps"
    fi
    rm "$1.pdf"
    ps2pdf "$1_oct.ps" "$1.pdf"

}  

build_page 1
build_page 2

pdftk 1.pdf 2.pdf cat output "${OUTPUT}.pdf"
```

The main part is when I do `cat > "$1_oct.ps" <<EOF`.

So, as KenS had suggested, the solution is prepend:

```
<< /BeginPage
{
    0.7 setgray

    0 280.66 moveto 595 280.66 lineto stroke
    0 561.33 moveto 595 561.33 lineto stroke

    198.33 0 moveto 198.33 842 lineto stroke
    396.66 0 moveto 396.66 842 lineto stroke
}
>> setpagedevice
```

Thanks